# Access UI components of a page fragment in adf from a phase listener (beforePhase or afterPhase)

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, oracle-adf

I'm new to Oracle ADF and I need help on getting access to the UI components of a page fragment on a JSPX file when the phase listeners of JSPX runs.

I have this .jspx file which contains an **af:region** inside of it. This region is connected to a page fragment (.jsff) file and I would like to access the UI components inside (e.g. inputText, etc.) of the page fragment from a page phase listener (either beforePhase or afterPhase events) of the JSPX file.

The page fragment is bound to a pageFlowScope bean and all its UI components. But when I tried to access the bean from the phase listener events, the UI components bound to the bean are not initialized yet and returns a NullPointerException.

I'm now thinking to try accessing the UI component by its "id" on the phase listener events. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can retreive the value of a binded inputText or any other ADF component in your phase listener directly from the view page El Expression. Here is a simple example : https://cedricleruth.com/how-to-retreive-the-value-of-an-iterator-binding-variable-programmatically-in-adf/

In your case it will look like :

```
//Below is a view example with values taken from an ADF View Object. Don't forget to add an MVCE next time
//<af:inputText id="it1" autoSubmit="true" value="#{bindings.YOUR_VO.YOUR_VO_ATTRIBUTE.inputValue}" />

public static void YOUR_PHASE_EVENT(PhaseEvent pe) {
    String inputTextValue= (String)this.resolveExpression("#{bindings.YOUR_VO.YOUR_VO_ATTRIBUTE.inputValue}");
    //Do whatever you want with it
}

/**
 * Method for taking a reference to a JSF binding expression and returning
 * the matching object (or creating it).
 * @param expression EL expression
 * @return Managed object
 * @author : Duncan Mills, Steve Muench and Ric Smith's JSFUtils class
 */
public static Object resolveExpression(String expression) {
    FacesContext facesContext = getFacesContext();
    Application app = facesContext.getApplication();
    ExpressionFactory elFactory = app.getExpressionFactory();
    ELContext elContext = facesContext.getELContext();
    ValueExpression valueExp = elFactory.createValueExpression(elContext, expression, Object.class);
    return valueExp.getValue(elContext);
}
```